# How do I colour a line chart based on Log10 of a column in my data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

According to a problem statement I have, I need to create a line chart from a dataset with 3 columns. But the colour needs to be `log10(col_3)`. I'm attempting to do this via matplotlib:

`data.plot(x = 'col_1', y = 'col_2')`

I have no idea how I could convert a column to colormap values using log10.

Edit: Based on the suggestion by @JohanC in the comments,

> [This example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) shows how multicolored line plots can be created with matplotlib.

I tried out the following code:-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


x = [20160101, 20160102, 20160103, 20160104, 20160105, 20160106, 20160107, 20160108]
y = [66.2, 71.76, 68.89, 64.63, 63.89, 67.09, 65.67, 65.42]
z = np.log10([710, 850, 900, 820, 720, 790, 670, 1070])

frame = pd.DataFrame({'col_1' : x,
                      'col_2' : y,
                      'col_3' : z})

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis = 1)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex = True, sharey = True)

norm = plt.Normalize(z.min(), z.max())
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap = 'viridis', norm = norm)

lc.set_array(z)
line = axs[0].add_collection(lc)
fig.colorbar(line, ax = axs[0])

plt.show()
```

I still get nothing but a blank graph, with a colourbar. If I replace the x,y,z values with what's provided in the matplotlib documentation example, I get the graph to show.
I'm really failing to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You could create an additional column with the log of col_3. But note that you need some special purpose code to have mutlicolored line plots. Keep in mind that the lines are between your data points, so you need to choose between the color of the starting or end point or do some interpolation.

Comment: [This example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) shows how multicolored line plots can be created with matplotlib.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out and report back here if I could work it out.

Comment: @JohanC I updated the question with my attempt results. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: You need to set the limits for the x and y axis because LineCollection doesn't set them automatically. `plt.xlim(min(x), max(x)); plt.ylim(min(y), max(y))` or `axs[0].set_xlim(min(x), max(x))`

Comment: That was like magic, it worked! So, if I understood this correctly, the graph scope was  outside the values of x and y. So, x and y values were being plotted outside the plot area?

Thanks a bunch!